# SQL Query to Delete in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have this below code but failing at getting it to delete the record, think i may be missing something.

```
<?php

//Open Database
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
     function __construct() {
         $this->open('Name.db');
     }
}

$db = new MyDB();

if(!$db){
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} 



//Select the Name Table
$sql =<<<EOF
    SELECT * FROM Name;
EOF;
$ret = $db->query($sql);

// Display The Data In a Table
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr><th>First name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Gender</th> <th></th> 
<th></th></tr>";
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['FirstName'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['LastName'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Gender'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="name.php?id=' . $row['FirstName'] . '">Delete</a>
    </td>';
echo "</tr>";
}


// check for id to be set and if it is delete the matching row from database 

if (isset($_GET['id']))
{

// puts the id value in the variable
$id = $_GET['id'];

// delete the entry

$db->exec("Delete FROM Name WHERE VALUES TeamName=$id;");

header("Location: name.php");

} else {
header("Location: name.php");}

$db->close();
?>
```

Is there something im missing as it still wont delete the entire row from the db file. It displays the table perfect just fails to delete the matching id Record.

Other delete querie i have tried is

```
$db->exec("Delete FROM Name (FirstName, LastName, Gender) WHERE VALUES 
FirstName=$id;");
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: You can't delete column vaulues, you can only delete a whole row. Please consult the manual on [how `DELETE` works](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html). Making up syntax randomly is not an effective way to learn MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete some of the values, you can either update them or just delete the entire row.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$db->exec("DELETE FROM Name WHERE TeamName=$id;");
```

and the other thing you need to do for safety is to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-escape-string.php) the $id variable, otherwise it's trouble waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

1) check whether the user you are using has the delete permission.

2)$db->exec("DELETE FROM `Name` WHERE `TeamName` = '".$id."'");